# C# Interface. Without specifying derrived class name

Tags: c#, interface

Is it possible to run a method in a derived class without having the base class know it's name. IE : finding out who implements ITest and running their methods specified in that class.

Weird question I know.

```
class BaseClass
{

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ITest f; //Null here. Want this to auto magically look for classes implementing ITest.  
        f.Run (); //And then run this. #NoReflection #NoBlackMagic. 
    }
}

public interface ITest //This will live in the same file as BaseClass
{
    void Run ();
}


class Derrived : ITest //Lives in another file
{
    #region ITest implementation

    public void Run ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Test was run");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The idea is. Lets say BaseClass is a user GUI on its own and the Derived class lives somewhere in another file.

It would be great to give someone the Base GUI class without him/her worry about the hardcoded ITest f = new ***Derived()*** class.

If there's more classes implementing ITest it's fine if they all Run();

I've seen some cool tricks with polymorphism but you still need to define the class names.

Maybe I'm missing the point of interfaces :(

Cheers oaks.

Comment: use namespace to achieve that?

Comment: auto magically but no black magic?

Comment: And why not by reflection? that would be the way to do this.

Comment: Doesn't MEF do something like this with class attribute decoration?

Comment: hahahaha. I can probably make all my controls public facing members, like a savage, and inherit the GUI class? But is it really a good idea to set controls.properties from within another class?

Comment: I was thinking with interfaces to pass the control via a parameter

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for 'dependency injection'. There are whole frameworks for that, but in the end it just comes down to passing in a concrete implementation of an interface, either as an argument or by setting a property.

Comment: What you are calling `BaseClass` is not, in fact, a base class. This is somewhat misleading. Similarly, what you are calling a derived class is not in this case a derived class. It is an *implementing* class. It's important to get this terminology correct.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Will make a note.

Comment: Checking which classes implement an interface at run-time can be useful in specific cases, but those are fairly rare. Cases where 'running all of them' is the desired behaviour are even more rare. Far more often you'll be passing in a concrete implementation: "you needed an `IDatabase`? Here's an `OracleDatabase` - or, here's a `MSSQLDatabase`" - and in both cases that function can do its job, without being tied to a specific implementation. It'd be strange for a low-level function to decide on it's own that it needs to write to all databases your program supports...

Comment: have a look at ServiceLocators, DI and Inversion of Controls

Comment: "It'd be strange for a low-level function to decide on it's own that it needs to write to all databases your program supports"

Very valid!

Answer (score 3):

Reflection would be the way to do this.

You can identify classes that implement `ITest` by enumerating all classes in the assembly:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var itestTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where (t => t.IsClass &&
                                            typeof(ITest).IsAssignableFrom(t));
foreach (var t in itestTypes)
{
    Console.WriteLine (t.ToString());
    ITest test = (ITest)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    test.Run();
}
```

## Dependency Injection

The other way to achieve this would be to use a dependency injection framework such as [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/). It's still using reflection under the hood.

Example: At somepoint you would register the class you want to use:

```
public static void RegisterClasses(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<ITest, Derived>();
}
```

This says "when something wants an `ITest`, make an instance of `Derived`".

Your code could look like this then:

```
ITest f = container.Resolve<ITest>();
f.Run();
```

The container will look at its registrations and choose to make `Derived`.

Other options are this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private ITest _test;

    public BaseClass(ITest test) //injected, no knowledge of IUnityContainer required
    {
       _test = test;
    }
}

//elsewhere:
container.Resolve<BaseClass>();
```

Or using the [`DependencyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.dependencyattribute.aspx):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Dependency]
    public ITest Test {get; set;}
}

//elsewhere:
container.Resolve<BaseClass>();
```

Bonus is it does not need parameterless constructor unlike the first bit of code, it will "resolve" all parameters in the same way in order to create `Derived`.